# Como instalar gem do Sass no Windows

Tags: ruby, gem, sass

Queria instalar a gem do Sass para poder compilar ele no Windows. Instalei o Ruby Installer normal e logo após fui na documentação do Sass de como executar ele no Windows utilizando modo console, porém quando vou executar a linha `gem install sass` para instalar a gem ele me retorna:

> local variable or method 'sass'

Como posso resolver isto?

Answer (score 1):

Qual versão do rails está usando?

Tente pelo Gemfile:

adicione a linha:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
```

depois rode o comando:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Eu preciso instalar esse Gemfile ? Pois coloquei no terminal e me retornou "Could not find 'sass-rails"

Comment: É um arquivo que fica na pasta raiz do seu projeto. Quando cria um novo projeto, esse arquivo ja é criado.